# How can I manage switching between wifi networks on raspberry pi?

Tags: networking, network-programming, raspberry-pi, wifi, embedded-linux

what I want to do is switch wifi networks from a Raspberry pi headlessly.
I am looking for a way that is very simple and that does not include any coding or using wpa_supplicant and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the connman package. The connmanctl commandline utility is most likely what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for the reply 
but what i am looking for is a way simple way to configure and switch wifi networks on a raspberry pi which should not include any command line inputs.

Comment: I am confused. You said headless. For me this means now graphical UI. Right?

Comment: no graphical UI no access over SSH
some other way to configure the wifi 
maybe creating a hotspot first and then switch from there
something like that

Comment: To get a better answer please be more precise in what you are trying to build/achieve. Please consider updating your original question. Thank you.